# How many memory accesses are required to render textures with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, memory-bandwidth

Using OpenGL, I want to calculate the necessary throughput to render a frame.

Assuming the worse case scenario, I have (1) a framebuffer and (2) 8 textures that are all fullscreen and the textures end up covering the whole screen (however, textures are likely flat rectangles, but not 1:1 scale).

So each pixel is tweaked from 9 RGB pixels (assuming all textures have some degree of transparency) and in an ideal world you would read exactly 9 pixels and then save the result in the framebuffer. Of course with filtering it could be reading more pixels (especially if the textures are not straight, etc.)

How do I compute an approximation of the number of memory access. So if my video board says it has a limit of 40Gb/s, I can make sure I have enough bandwidth to support the full load?

Some details as requested in comments:

Frames / texture sizes: 3840 x 2160 (4K)
Expected frame rate: 30 FPS
GPU: NVidia (one of the newest like Maxwell or Pascal at least)

Comment: What size textures are you working with? What refresh rate do you want to achieve? Even most embedded GPUs can support 60Hz at 1080p so you're probably fine for simple kernel functions that access a handful of pixels at a time. I'd suggest testing your code on the slowest, crappiest computer you have to get a sense of how ridiculously fast OpenGL shaders can be in practice.

Comment: @tadman Right, we're looking at 4K which is why I wonder whether I'll be fine. The card I'm looking at says it has a max. of 59.7 Gb/s and I think I will need about 40 Gb/s (because I would like to have multiple texture sizes for some of the textures). Testing with my existing cards would certainly be a good idea, though. I just can't output the 4K at the moment.

Comment: Testing's the only way to know for sure. I've written what I thought was awful shader code and it ran fine on 2010-vintage notebook GPU hardware, so sometimes your intuition is going to lead you to be far too paranoid to be productive. Keep yourself grounded by running tests, and always push your tests to the breaking point to know how much headroom you have. If you can get 400FPS on crappy hardware I think you're good.